# Setting Selection as Range

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please hint at what i might be doing wrong here? For now I am effectively trying to do a Ctrl-A command to do a select all on a block of data in vba. Then i want that selection to be saved as a range, so that I can use it later.

```
Dim rngAdData As Range
.....
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Set rngAdData = Selection
Range(rngAdData).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPla....  //<----
```

The last line gives me a `run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object 'Global' failed`

When I do it the following way, it works

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPla....
```

But doing it this way is cumbersome because I need to use that range again here

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("....").Sort
    .SetRange Range(Selection) //<---
```

The line being pointed to gives me that same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range(rngAdData)` is feeding a range to a range. Just use `rngAdData.AdvancedFilter`

It's the same idea on your second problem. Use this syntax instead.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("....").Sort
    .SetRange Selection
```

With that said you should be using another means of getting your desired range other than using `Select` or `Selection` statements. Something like this should work better

```
Dim rngAdData As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet, bottomMostRow As Long, rightMostColumn As Long
Set sht = ActiveSheet
With sht
    bottomMostRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    rightMostColumn = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Set rngAdData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(bottomMostRow, rightMostColumn))
End With
```

Comment: you blew it wide open for me, thanks so much. it's been a while since my last vba project. just a tiny question though, are `.Select` statements bad?

Comment: @mango They are slow and not reliable. You're much better off explicitly saying what you want purely in code rather than relying on changes in the cursor position. You code won't be vulnerable to someone clicking their mouse in the middle of execution and messing everything up. It also causes the screen to change which is slow too.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Range("A1").Select
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, Sheets("sheet1").Range("E7:H8"), False
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help. I'm getting a compile error though. says argument not optional at: `rngAdData.AdvancedFilter`

Comment: do you want to filer with any criteria ?

Comment: yes i do, i'm sorry for omitting: `rngAdData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= Sheets("...").Range("E7:H8"), Unique:=False`

Comment: make sure you have removed rounded brackets. The code works fine at my end.

Comment: If you're trying that code as written I don't think you can filter on a single cell. In fact you need more than one row at least. Needs a header row and some data.