# VBA Compile error: Syntax error while trying to set range for chart

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to make a macro that creates a chart from three selected columns. It works fine but I am trying to make column 1 (A:A) always apart of the range and then just select the remaining to columns I need as there are multiple charts i need to make from a data sheet

```
Sub Charter()

    Dim my_range    As Range

    Set my_range = ("A:A", Selection)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=my_range

    Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

I get an

> "Compile error: Syntax error"

at the `Set my_range = ("A:A", Selection)`

Comment: Have you tried `Set my_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")` ?

Comment: That works to get "A:A" but I still need the range to include `Selection`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Selection as Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140786/setting-selection-as-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use `Union`:

```
Set my_range = Union(Selection, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
```